# LinkedIn android app embedded web browser not loading website

Tags: javascript, android, webview, linkedin-api

The LinkedIn Android app embedded web browser is not loading pages shared from our web site/web app. It appears our site's javascript is not loading completely, or not being run.

As a result, clicking through on a shared link within the LinkedIn Android app leads only to a page with our page loading indicator.

Here is an example of a link that cannot be viewed on the LinkedIn Android app's web browser, while working fine in the LinkedIn iOS app's web browser:

https://journey2health.com/articles/propaganda-shouts-truth-whispers-zEApck

It seems likely the Android app is using a WebView control to display information shared from third party sites. Is anyone aware of documentation regarding known limitations of the Android app's WebView or ways to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link, the problem lies within your Javascript.

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en

Android WebView does not have have a limitation that would cause this.

Comment: Thanks but that reference link doesn't speak to or address the problem. We're providing OG tags for proper previews. There's also no problem opening our site within the LinkedIn iOS app.

An Android WebView control is fairly limited out of the box and requires some work before it can function as a Web browser:

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

... finally, I'm not sure they're using a WebView, although it would be the obvious choice.

Comment: Where can I reach the link you provided from the Android LinkedIn App?

Comment: Here is the link we shared in LinkedIn:

https://journey2health.com/articles/propaganda-shouts-truth-whispers-zEApck

Here is the article as it was posted in LI:
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6324583219580665856/